# How to mock a private method using PowerMock with Mockito and TestNG

Tags: java, maven, testng, mockito, powermock

I am trying to use powermock to mock a private method, but my PowerMock is not recognized in `MockitoBusinessOperation MockitoBusinessOperation = PowerMock.createPartialMock(MockitoBusinessOperation.class, "inTestMethod");` . I used maven and the dependencies for mockito and powermock are defined in my pom file

```
<dependency>   
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I don't know if the error is related to powermock with TestNG or I am doing some mistake in my code.

```
@PrepareForTest(MockitoBusinessOperation.class)
@Test(enabled = true)
public void testReCalculatePrepaids() throws Exception {
    MockitoBusinessOperation MockitoBusinessOperation = PowerMock.createPartialMock(MockitoBusinessOperation.class, "inTestMethod");
    PowerMock.expectPrivate(MockitoBusinessOperation, "inTestMethod",   Id).andReturn("working fine");

    when(MockitoBusinessService.creditReport(this.Id)).thenReturn(new String("Decline by only Me")); 

    String report = MockitoBusinessService.creditReport(this.Id);
    String mainReport = MockitoBusinessOperation.creditAproved(this.Id);  
}
```

someone has an idea or any clue lead to the solution

Comment: You should really consider using white spaces instead of tabs in your editor, that's why the formatting doesn't copy over very well. The amount of space in a white space (1) is universal, tabs are not.

Comment: Thanks for the format fix

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Mockito_testng_maven) your maven file should have the following definitions:

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>1.5</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>  
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this way

```
  @Test
        public  void  commandEndHandlerTest() throws  Exception
        {
            Method retryClientDetail_privateMethod =yourclass.class.getDeclaredMethod("Your_function_name",null);
            retryClientDetail_privateMethod.setAccessible(true);
            retryClientDetail_privateMethod.invoke(yourclass.class, null);
        }
```